# Get Notification of App in Background

Tags: c#, windows-8, background, windows-runtime

Is there a way to know if my App was put into the background, but not actually suspended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever the user sends your app to the background, it is suspended. To be exact, Windows [supposedly wait a couple of seconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx#App_suspend) to see if the user will immediately switch back before sending the application into `Suspended` state. Right before this switch occurs, `Suspending` event is raised to give the application opportunity to save its state in the time period of 5 seconds.

From this point the application can either be reactivated when the user switches back to it or terminated if Windows decides it needs more resources. In either case the application doesn't receive any additional notifications.

Comment: Sometimes it can take quite a while to get suspended though. Nothing else I can handle earlier?

Comment: @gamernb Not that I know of. Maybe someone else will prove me wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [VisibilityChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx#App_visibility) but note the caveat

> The visibility event is not serialized with the resume or activation
>   events. Don't assume that these events come in a particular order.